# Quais são as API's para se criar interface gráfica em Java?

Tags: java, api, aplicação-desktop, gui

Existe alguma outra ferramenta além do Swing, AWT e o JavaFX para se criar interface gráfica desktop para aplicações Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É possível usar qualquer biblioteca que esteja disponível, você pode fazer sua própria biblioteca. Em última análise é claro que todas estas bibliotecas terão que acessar a API gráfica para *desktop* dos sistemas operacionais onde ela tem intenção de rodar. No mínimo terá que acessar as primitivas gráficas como *pen* e *brush* além de ter alguma forma de acesso à tela em si, comumente será através de *windows*.

Algumas das bibliotecas mais conhecidas disponíveis para Java são:

- [Qt Jambi](https://github.com/qtjambi) - *Binding* da [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) que roda em diversas plataformas.
- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) - É uma evolução da AWT e preferida quando se deseja ter acesso nativo aos recursos de *desktop* de diversas plataformas.
- [Java-Gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/) - *Binding* da [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) para quem está acostumado com ela ou acha nela solução para alguma necessidade específica.

Além disso existem algumas extensões para os *frameworks* existentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quais seriam essas extensões?

Comment: Não vou me lembrar de muitas mas o que me vem à cabeça agora seria o SwingX, JGoodies.