# Existe Framework para programação em JAVA Desktop?

Tags: java

Existe um kit de desenvolvimento gráfico para a linguagem Java, para aplicações desktop?

Comment: Veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52644/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-apis-para-se-criar-interface-gr%c3%a1fica-em-java) e suas respostas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. Existe o Swing que o próprio netbeans usa e já vem instalado com ele, mas tmb pode ser usado no eclipse. Existe outros que não me recordo. Uma possibilidade é tmb trabalhar com Java FX que é uma outra forma de criar apps para desktop com Java.